# Binary variable uncorrelatedness implies independence

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reading a statistics paper. It said generally uncorrelatedness does not imply independence. But if the case is two binary variables, then the uncorrelatedness can imply independence. How to show this statement?

Comment: Could you link the paper?

Comment: "Uncorrelatedness implying independence: Although
uncorrelatedness usually does not imply independence, it is well
known that it does for two binary variables."

Comment: The paper is Zhang, K. (2019). BET on independence

Comment: It’s also true for normally distributed random variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be two binary random variables with $P(X=1)=p_X,P(Y=1)=p_Y$.

Note that zero correlation implies zero covariance and we get:

$$Cov[X,Y] = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] = 0 \implies E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=p_Xp_Y$$

For brevity let's define the events $X_i:= \{X=i\}$ and $Y_i:=\{Y=i\}$

Define $Z=XY \in \{0,1\}$

$$E[XY]= P(Z=1) = P(X_1,Y_1)=p_Xp_Y \implies X_1 \perp Y_1$$

In general, $A\perp B \implies A^c \perp B, \;A \perp B^c, \;A^c \perp B^c$ ([see here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/408/408general2.pdf)) therefore,

$$X_1 \perp Y_1 \implies X_1^c \perp Y_1, \;X_1 \perp Y_1^c, \;X_1^c \perp Y_1^c$$

This happens to exhaust the sample space of the joint experiment $(X,Y)$ so we conclude:

$$X_i \perp Y_j\;\;\forall i,j \in \{0,1\} \implies X \perp Y$$